# Restcomm sip endpoint transfer

Tags: restcomm

Does this work ?
I tried transfer from one sip point to another (eyebeam to xlite) and it didn't work.(i used the x-fer button on eyebeam).

Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restcomm-Connect doesn't support https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5589 yet. feel free to open a github issue at https://github.com/RestComm/Restcomm-Connect/issues/new with the logs of your test so it can be scheduled on the roadmap. Would you be interested to contribute the feature ?